# Prove that $\lim_{x\to 1} 7x^2 - 3x^3 = 4$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\lim_{x\to 1} 7x^2 - 3x^3 = 4$

My try is the following:
To begin, note that if x is a real number, satisfies $0<|x-1|<1,$ , then (I feel like I need some reverse triangle inequality but I cannot figure out).

Now, for ε>0 given, define  δ = min{sth, sth},
Then, if $0<|x-1|<δ,$
it follows that $|7x^2+3x^3-4| = |x-1|*|-3x^2+4x+4|$....sth

When you see sth, it means I need your help on that.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just say "it's continuous so I can just plug $1$ wherever I see $x$"? It'd nearly be easier to prove that $\Bbb 1$ and $x\mapsto x$ are continuous and then prove that sums and products of continuous function are.

Comment: you mean |x| < |x - 1| < 1?

Comment: @xavierm02 That's not sufficient. I can plug $x$ into the Dirichlet function but it is nowhere continuous. Once could show that $x$ is continuous, products of cont. functions are continuous, constant multiples of cont. functions are continuous, sums of continuous functions are continuous, then conclude the above function is continuous at $x=1$ and that the limit must be $f(1)=4$ is the limit. But that is extreme overkill for such a problem, which only needs the definition of a limit at a point.

Comment: @xaviermo2 : there is a (real-analysis) tag, which suggests maybe an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ approach is desired.  If it were for a calculus class, I'd do it as you say.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this might work.

$$
|7x^2 - 3x^3 - 4|=|-3x^3+(3x^2-3x^2)+7x^2 + (4x-4x) - 4| = |-3x^2(x-1) +  4x(x-1) + 4(x-1)| \leq |x-1||-3x^2 + 4x + 4|
$$